# Can you use hero points to reroll flat checks?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

The [rules regarding hero points](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=427) say:

> [...]
> You can spend your Hero Points in one of two ways. Neither of these is an action, and you can spend Hero Points even if you aren't able to act. You can spend a Hero Point on behalf of your familiar or animal companion.
>
> - Spend 1 Hero Point to **reroll a check.** You must use the second result. This is a fortune effect (which means you can't use more than 1 Hero Point on a check).
> - Spend all your Hero Points (minimum 1) to avoid death. You can do this when your dying condition would increase. You lose the dying condition entirely and stabilize with 0 Hit Points. You don't gain the wounded condition or increase its value from losing the dying condition in this way, but if you already had that condition, you don't lose it or decrease its value.

When it says check, does it include Flat Checks like attacking a hidden enemy? Based on the phrasing, I'd assume it does, but since Flat Checks seem different to other checks, I'd like some confirmation.

Comment: @ESCE Thanks for that.

Answer (score 11):

### Yes, this works

The rules for a flat check say:

> When the chance something will happen or fail to happen is based purely on chance, you’ll attempt a flat check. A flat check never includes any modifiers, bonuses, or penalties—you **just roll a d20** and compare the result on the die to the DC.

Since you roll a check, you can use Hero Points to reroll the check. It does not matter if you can use other modifiers on the roll or not.

Comment: I'm going to need you to stop answering questions so accurately and quickly so I can get some...

Comment: @lfusao Oops ... apologies, I will step back a bit. Do you have a system preference?

Comment: I'm completely kidding. A responsive community is good for everybody.